# Understanding how Java's replaceFirst works with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a String, `<parameter name="Browser" value="chrome" />`. I'd like to replace `chrome` with `Firefox`. My relevant Java code:

```
l = l.replaceFirst("value=\"*\"", "value=\"" + browser + '"');
```

Is turning the original String into

`<parameter name="Browser" value="Firefox"chrome" />`. I'm confused how `chrome"` is not getting removed since the regex in `replaceFirst` matches the opening and closing parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first regex, `value=\"*\"`, the `\"*\"` is matching 0 or more `"` characters, not any number of characters as you intended. The correct syntax for this would be `value=\".*\"`.

You can test out a regex on http://regexr.com/ to get an idea of how your regex will work, with syntax highlighting.